# Are chanukah menorahs lit from the left or the right?

Tags: lighting, chanuka, menora-chanukia

There are different authorities that state the chanukah menora should be lit from the left or the right. Which is correct?

Answer (score 8):

20th c. rabbi and legal decisor Yisrael Meir Kagan wrote in the [Mishna B'rura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishna%5FBerura) ([Orach Chayim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orach%5FChayim) 676) that the guiding principle in lighting the candles is never to pass one's hand past a candle without lighting it since that would constitute passing up an opportunity to perform a [mitzva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitzvah). So, assuming a right-handed person standing slightly to the left of and facing a m'nora, one would light the leftmost candle first since it is closest, then proceed to the right.

Comment: This was the first real answer to a real question on Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 7):

Despite the fact that everyone seems to assume you light from left to right (don't take my word for it; try a simple Google search!) there actually is a difference of opinion.

The following information is taken directly from [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Lighting_Chanukah_Candles) (with some very minor editing by me for formatting purposes):

> - Maharik (Responsa 183, cited by Beit Yosef 676:5) writes that **on the first night, one should light the rightmost candle and on subsequent
>     nights should add a candle to the left and light the new one first
>     such that one lights from left to right (the way English is written)**.
>     He bases his argument on the Gemara (Sotah 15b) that a person always
>     should turn to the right, which the Mordechai (Shabbat 2:268) applied
>     to lighting chanuka candles. The Shulchan Aruch 676:5 codifies this as
>     halacha. This is also the opinion of the Arizal (Shaar Kavanot pg
>     108c), Nagid VeMitzvah (26:72), Maharil (quoted by the Magan Avraham
>     676:5).
> - The Trumat Hadeshen 106 agrees that **if one is lighting opposite the Mezuzah then one should light from left to right with the new candle
>     is always the leftmost candle** which is within a Tefach of the door.
>     However, **if there’s no mezuzah and one is lighting on the right side
>     of the door as one enters then one should light right to left so that
>     the new candle is always the rightmost candle** and is within a Tefach
>     of the door. The Sh”t Maharshal 85 agrees with the Trumat HaDeshen.
>     However, the Bet Yosef 676:5 quotes the Trumat HaDeshen and argues
>     that there shouldn’t be any difference **whether one is lighting on the
>     left or right of the door one should always light the new candle first
>     and light from left to right**.
> - However, the Levush (676:5) and Taz (676:6), however, argue that the Gemara means in one’s first decision between right and left one should
>     go right, but afterwards one may continue to follow that path even if
>     that means going left. Therefore, they rule that **on the first night,
>     the candle is placed in the leftmost position, and on the subsequent
>     nights, the candles are put to the right of the previous candles and
>     are lit from right to left**. This is also the opinion of the Sh”t Panim
>     Meirot 1:98 and Sh”t Semach Tzedek O”C 67.
> - A third approach is that of the Gr”a (Bei’ur HaGra 676:5 and Maaseh Rav 240). He writes that **one always should light the candle closest to
>     the door first, even if it is not the newest candle and even if it
>     means lighting from right to left**. This is also recorded in Maaseh Rav
>     (Siman 240).
> - Halacha: Mishna Brurah 676:9 quotes the Bet Yosef and the Gra and concludes **one can do like either one**. The Pri HaChadash, Bear Sheva
>     (Sotah 15b), Nezirut Shimshon (Sotah 15b), Sh”t Chatam Sofer O”C 187,
>     Chazon Ovadiah (Chanuka pg 33) argue on the Levush and hold like S”A.
>     Kovetz Hamoedim (Moriah pg 61), Evan Israel (9 pg 129a), Sadeh HaAretz
>     O”C 3:33, and Nehar Mitzrayim Chanuka 7 argue on the Gra and hold like
>     S”A. The Kitzur S”A 139:11, Kaf HaChaim 676:31, Aruch HaShulchan
>     676:11, Natai Gavriel (Chanuka 28:2, pg 177), and Yalkut Yosef (Moadim
>     pg 229) write that the halacha and minhag follow Shulchan Aruch. **Rav
>     Mordechai Willig (Hilchos Chanuka and Purim #1, 37-8) observed that
>     the minhag is like the S”A.**
> - Rav Hershel Schachter (Halachipedia Article 5773 #10) said that **common practice is to put the candles in from right to left**. He
>     explained that the idea is to start the candles within a tefach of the
>     doorway.

For visual application, see this photo from Nitei Gavriel (Chanukah pg 637):[image: this photo]:

Answer (score 1):

one should place the candles from right to left and light them from left to right.

Comment: Source? _______

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/22675