# Fill m'nora in order?

Tags: halacha, menora-chanukia

I know that (at least when lighting at a window), one lights the *Chanuka m'nora* from left to right: the new lamp first and rightward from there. I've seen people careful to fill them with oil (or candles) in the same order; I've also [seen](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3511) that one should fill them in the opposite order. Is either of these a 'real' custom (with a basis) or *halacha*, and, if so, what is its basis or reason?

Comment: Part of starting on the left is standing to the left of the _m'nora_ while lighting so that that is the first candle you meet when approaching the _m'nora_.

Comment: @WAF, yes, and that's closely related to why I wrote "(at least when lighting at a window)". See _MB_.

Comment: Why are you spelling it "m'nora" instead of "menorah"?

Comment: @Ariel, why would you transliterate it "menorah," rather than "m'nora"?

Comment: @Ariel I usually use [this transliteration scheme](http://web.archive.org/web/20080509063200/http://www.math.wustl.edu/~msh210/crusade/transliterate.html).

Comment: @msh210 It's awesome that you have that documented.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Because that's how people searching for the concept will spell it. Now that menorah is in the dictionary you don't get to pick your own transliteration even if it's more accurate or consistent.

Comment: @Ariel, some minority of the time, people will search using alternative transliterations. Interesting point, though, about this being an English word as well as a Hebrew word. I agree that that may skew search-preference frequency qualitatively more than the general relative popularity of various transliteration schemes. On the other hand, it's not like we require using standard English versions of various proper names that have them, e.g. "Abraham." (And it's not like the 'b' for a vet is necessarily less "correct" than an 'e' for a sheva' na'.) What do you think, msh210?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think demanding anglicizations instead of transliterations where the former exist is not a bad idea, but what "exists" (i.e. which English dictionary or corpus we use to determine whether something is an English word) is then open to discussion. We should raise this on [meta.judaism.se] instead of continuing the conversation here.

Comment: Followup on these comments: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1417